# Creating a multiplatform Lib for netstandard2.0 and net6 - trouble with System.Runtime

Tags: c#, .net, multitargeting

While migrating to net6 in company we want to habe some libraries for netstandard2.0 and net6 as well. (we skipped shorttime support net5)

Having a library as local reference: as well.
Having the library as proprietary nuget source: Problem referencing System.Runtime

Referencing the library from a project, having netCore3.1 as Framework

> ... uses 'System.Runtime, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' which has a higher version than
> referenced assembly 'System.Runtime' with identity 'System.Runtime,
> Version=4.2.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' ...

But there exists no System.Runtime in nuget.

The multitarget Lib is deployed in a docker container.

- Is there something missing?

Comment: is your lib targeting `.netstandard` and which version?

Comment: <TargetFrameworks>netstandard2.0; net6.0</TargetFrameworks>

Answer (score 0):

If it helps anyone I found that both netstandard2.0 and net6.0 libraries were targeting net6.0 (Can see this in dotPeek). Instead of one targeting 6 and one targeting 2.0. Problem was the build command had an output folder so both frameworks were outputted to the same location, meaning one overwrote the other.

```
dotnet build "****" -c Release -o /app/build
```

Should be

```
dotnet build "****" -c Release
```